# Ask for help to build a truck booking system in powerapps

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Firstly I am a beginner of powerapps. I want to create a truck booking app. My process flow is as follows.

1. Customer service (CS) needs to fill Booking request - Requester Name,Customer Name,Customer address, ShipperAddress,Type (Pick up or deliver),Container size (20' or 40' or 40'High cube).
2. After filling those filelds and click on submit by CS, Truck manager need to assign driver and driver's contact to that Booking request.
3. After finished above process, data should be displayed to Driver's view.
4. Driver should click on "Finish" after work is done.
   I created 3 lists (CSbookingList, DriversList, TruckList).
   DriversList [DriverID,Driver Name, Driver Contact]
   TruckList [Truck No].

CSBookingList [ID,Requester Name,Customer Name,Customer address, ShipperAddress,Type (Pick up or deliver),Container size (20' or 40' or 40'High cube)].
? I have no idea how to merge driver assign form and truck assign form in one screen.
? I want all complete data to driver screen because drivers can only view their respective assigned booking data.
Does anyone have suggestions for this flow? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs is more related to PowerApps.You could go to [this forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Community/ct-p/PowerApps1#) which is dedicated to PowerApps for more professional help.